# Why are column breakpoints in the debugger for non-function calls?

Tags: javascript, debugging

[The mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint#unconditional_breakpoints) the says that column breakpoints are given in the debugger only to function calls:

> If the line contains multiple function calls, each one will be
> given a small blue arrow icon to the left of it. These are called column
> breakpoints, and allow you to set the breakpoint to happen exactly on any
> one of the function calls in the line (or multiple calls), by clicking on each
> relevant one.

However column breakpoints are also set in for loops where no function calls were made. Below is an image i created that highlights the problem:

[Imgur Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DSOl.png)

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that column breakpoints are available *only* at function calls, does it? I really don't see a problem here, the more possible breakpoint locations you get the better.

Comment: @Bergi So if column breakpoints are not only set a function calls, in what other scenarios are they placed as well?

Comment: In every place where the engine allows execution to be interrupted, and which the devtools support. There is no requirement (like the JavaScript specification) for this, it's a best-effort implementation. If you're annoyed by the outdated documentation, file an issue with MDN.

Comment: @Bergi I mean i don't see anything wrong with the specification but it might lack information on that part because it only mentions function calls to be associated with column breakpoints(wich is obviously not always the case). But i'm not that desperate either to file an issue to MDN either.